# Laravel Multiple linking column in another table with relationships?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a league table in Laravel but I'm running into some issues with guess what, relationships, again. They never seem to work for me in Laravel. It's like they hate me.

I have a modal for matches

```
<?php

namespace App\Database;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Match extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $table = 'matches';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

And a modal for teams, but with a matches() function

```
<?php

namespace App\Database;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $table = 'teams';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function matches() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Database\Match', 'team_one_id, team_two_id');
    }
}
```

I think the issue comes with `team_one_id, team_two_id` as the teams primary key could be in either one of them columns for the other table. When calling `count()` on `matches()` it throws an error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'matches.team_one_id, team_two_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `matches` where `matches`.`team_one_id, team_two_id` = 1 and `matches`.`team_one_id, team_two_id` is not null)

Comment: Take a look at the second parameter in `$this->hasMany`

Comment: can you provide matches and teams table structure.

Answer (score 1):

> This way you can implement it, Add these relationship and a method in Team Model

```
 public function homeMatches() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Database\Match', 'team_one_id');
 }

 public function awayMatches() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Database\Match', 'team_two_id');
 }

 public function matches() {
    return $this->homeMatches->merge($this->awayMatches);
 }
```

> Now Fetch the data

```
$team = Team::find(1);
$matches = $team->matches(); //now it will fetch all matches for both columns
```

> If you want to fetch matches as attributes then you can add one method
>   in your Team model

```
public function getMatchesAttribute()
{
   return $this->homeMatches->merge($this->awayMatches);
}
```

Now you can fetch the matches as `$matches = $team->matches;`

> Here is the difference

`$team->matches` returns `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`

**And**

`$team->matches()` returns `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\{Relation Name}`

You can't use `matches` in Eager loading like `Team::with('matches')` because `matches` is not a relationship and that causing your Error. What you can do is add `homeMatches` and `awayMatches` in eager loading and then call `$team->matches()`.

```
$teams = Team::with('homeMatches', 'awayMatches')->get(); 
$teams->each(function ($team) {
    print_r($team);
    print_r($team->matches()); 
});
```

Comment: No, if you read my question you would notice I need the column to be `team_one_id` OR `team_two_id`, your answer would basically break my code.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for updating your answer. Your update causes an error. `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist.`

Comment: @wilino did you try `$matches = $team->matches();` not `$matches = $team->matches;`

Comment: @walino i have tested the code and it is working perfectly

Comment: @walino i have updated my answer with description, hope this time it help you

Answer (score 0):

can you try this syntax

return $this->hasMany('modelPath', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

Comment: This is a bad answer. All you've done is copy+paste the Laravel documentation. This doesn't show how to do multiple keys

Answer (score 0):

Does Match table have a column maned 'team_id'?
because it's the default naming convention in the laravel docs for mapping the tables.

if you do have the column and populate the data you can just remove the foreign & local keys from matches() relationship. you don't need it. Laravel will automatically map it for you.

if you do not have the 'team_id' on Matches table please add the column and add the respective team ids for matches.

```
<?php

namespace App\Database;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $table = 'teams';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function matches() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Database\Match');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer makes no sense. How can you only have 1 column for 2 teams in a match?